# How would you write Junit tests for this code?

Tags: java, testing, junit

Im new to java and practising my coding, how would I write some Junit tests for this code without changing it? I wanted to write some Junits to see if the output is correct. Could someone provide one such example?
Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
package returnOnInvestment;

import java.util.Scanner;

/**
   This program compares CD /Investment plans input by the year
   broken down by the requirements below:

   This program creates a table of compound interest investment growth over time
   Broken down by: a) year b) balance at end of year
   Finance formula of A= P(1+ r/n)^n*t is used:
   A = Future Value         | P = Initial Investment
   r = annual interest rate |n = times interest is compounded/year
   t = years invested
*/ 

public class BestInvesment
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        String bestBankName = "";
        double bestGrowth = 0;
        boolean done = false;

        while(!done)
        {
            System.out.print("Plan name (one word, Q to quit): ");
            String bankName = in.next();
            if (bankName.equals("Q"))
            {
                done = true;
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.print("Please enter your principal investment: ");
                final double PRINCIPAL_INVESTMENT = in.nextDouble();
                System.out.print("Please enter the annual interest rate: ");
                double iRate = in.nextDouble();
                System.out.print("Please enter number of times interest is compounded per year:  ");
                final double INCREMENT = 1;//in.nextDouble();      
                System.out.print("Enter number of years: ");
                int nyears = in.nextInt();

                iRate = iRate/100; System.out.println("iRate:" + iRate);

                //Print the table of balances for each year

                for (int year = 1; year <= nyears; year++)
                {
                    double MULTIPLIER = INCREMENT * year;
                    System.out.println("Multiplier: " + MULTIPLIER); // I've included this print statement to show that the multiplier changes with each passing year
                    double interest = 1 + (iRate/INCREMENT);
                    double balance = PRINCIPAL_INVESTMENT;
                    double growth =  balance * Math.pow(interest, MULTIPLIER);
                    growth = growth - PRINCIPAL_INVESTMENT;                      
                    balance = balance + growth;                                  
                    System.out.printf("Year: %2d  Interest Earned:   $%.2f\t   Ending Balance:   $%.2f\n", year, growth, balance);

                    if (bestBankName.equals("") || bestGrowth > growth) // || bestBankName > growth
                    {
                        bestBankName = bankName;  // bestBankName = bankName
                        bestGrowth = growth; // mostGrow = growth
                    }
                    System.out.println("Earning with this option: " + growth);        
                }
            }

        } 
        System.out.println("Best Growth: " + bestBankName);
        System.out.println("Amount Earned: " + bestGrowth);       
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As it is, this code is very difficult to test, which it is a symptom of some design smells.

One thing to realize is that you are severely violating the Single Responsibility Principle.

Your code which is just one blob is doing the following things:

- printing stuff to console
- getting input from the user
- doing some calculation
- coordinating all this

Since this is in the realm of practicing, I would heavily refactor the code into separate classes. Those then should be easily testable, especially the one doing the calculation, since it will have just some simple methods where you can pass some values as arguments, and check the results

For testing the input and output classes note that you can change System.in and System.out to point to your own implementations, so you can create those to facilitate testing. You might want to look into a mocking framework for this (e.g. Mockito) but it is perfectly possible without such framework.